# И снова сравнительный оборот

Tags: сравнительный-оборот

Есть два случая:

В спектакле по разработанному заранее художественному сценарию он позволил водить себя (,) как бычка на веревочке (,)  организаторам­-городничим, не проявив своей инициативы и не разобравшись с ними, как сказочный царь Гвидон с поварихой и ткачихой.

Я позволил себе ударять по зубьям. Они отлетали (,) как сахарные.

Как здесь лучше расставить знаки препинания? Мне кажется, что и в первом и во втором случаях запятых не нужно.

Comment: Там спектакль был разработан по сценарию или он позволял по заранее разработанному сценарию?

Comment: Первое, конечно. Это все был спектакль.

Answer (score 4):

А мне  кажется, что здесь именно сравнительные обороты и запятые нужны.

Про бычка поговорка "быть бычку на верёвочке", а здесь с таким бычком сравнивается.

И "отлетали как сахарные" - такого фразеологизма не знаю.

Эти случаи допускают двоякую пунктуацию. Розенталь пишет:

Примечание. При анализе подобных примеров мы исходим из авторской пунктуации и пытаемся ее объяснить, что, как известно, является делом весьма сложным. Так, сопоставляя приведенные выше предложения из стихотворений М. Ю. Лермонтова с его же фразой Она ускользнёт, как змея, порхнёт и умчится,как птичка, мы можем допустить, что в последнем случае автору важно было создать художественные образы путем, так сказать, чистого сравнения (подобно змее, подобно птичке, хотя сравнение сохраняется и в сочетаниях ускользнёт змеёй, умчится птичкой, но с добавочным оттенком образа действия).

Точно так же в стихе Гляжу, как безумный, на чёрную шаль (П.) значение ‘подобно безумцу’ преобладает над значением ‘гляжу безумцем’.

Поэтому некоторые предложения допускают двоякое толкование и, следовательно, двоякую пунктуацию; ср.: Он умер, как настоящий герой(подобно герою’). — Он умер как настоящий герой (‘умер героем’).

У нас тоже авторское понимание. Пишет инженер Кауфман о "передачах", на конце которых металлические зубья, которые разлетаются так же легко, как сахарные предметы. На первом месте  у него всё-таки сравнение. Нельзя заменить творительным падежом, не фразеологизм. И он поставил запятую, чтобы подчеркнуть лёгкость, с какой ломаются зубья. А как лучше - это как понимает автор.

И первый случай такой же - как автор понимает. Я вижу именно сравнение: позволил водить себя так же, как бычка водят на верёвочке.

Comment: Людмила, они не разлетались, они ***отлетали***. Это очень разные вещи.

Comment: Ну да, отлетали, отламывались. Всё равно сравнивается по степени лёгкости, а обстоятельственное  значение   здесь  явно вторично.

Comment: Да, все правильно. Пишет инженер М. Кауфман. Но в первом случае запятых он не поставил... Вот я и думаю... Хотя после всех высказанных размышлений мне уже тоже начинает казаться, что есть необходимость в запятых... Во всяком случае теперь это все яснее... Спасибо!

Comment: @Alenka  а дайте ссылку на этого Кауфмана. Людмила ведь его где-то нашла.

Comment: *Всё равно сравнивается по степени лёгкости, а обстоятельственное значение здесь явно вторично* - пока текст не увижу, не поверю. Хотя если там у и автора обособление, то может быть, конечно. Но все равно вашей уверенности у меня нет и в помине.

Answer (score 1):

В обоих случаях **можно не обособлять оборот с союзом КАК**.

(1) В спектакле по разработанному заранее художественному сценарию он позволил **организаторам-городничим** водить себя **как бычка на веревочке**  (= как привязанного) , не проявив своей инициативы и не разобравшись с ними, как сказочный царь Гвидон с поварихой и ткачихой.

Водить себя (как?) ― здесь желательно наличие необособленного обстоятельства, которое будет выделяться логически: не просто водить, а водить **как на веревочке.**

Также желательно переставить дополнение.

Сравнить (необособленный вариант): Он за нею **как бычок на верёвочке**!

(2) Я позволил себе ударять по зубьям. Они отлетали **как  (= будто) сахарные**.

Нераспространенный оборот  не обособляется, при отсутствии паузы он будет выделен логическим ударением.

Comment: Вот мне тоже кажется, что просто _водить_ - это звучит как-то незавершенно... А во втором случае просто запятая режет глаз, хотя про обстоятельства образа действия здесь не скажешь...

Comment: Они отлетали легко, как сахарные. Можно составить ряд однородных обстоятельств.

Comment: Да, но в исходном предложении слова "легко" нет...

Comment: Я имела в виду, что "как сахар" - это тоже обстоятельство, если может находиться в однородных отношениях с наречием  "легко". Отлетали (как? каким образом?) как сахар.

Answer (score 1):

В отношении первого примера полностью согласен с Людмилой. Сравнение и как следствие желательность обособления очевидны.

По поводу второго. Тут надо со смыслом определиться.
Если это зубья как сахарные (не настоящие, что ли), то да, некое сравнение.
А вот если "отлетали как сахарные" - то вариант образа действия кажется вполне реальным.
Что такое "отлетать как сахарный"?
Рискну предположить, что речь идет о жженом сахаре (люди постарше еще помнят это лакомство), карамели. Есть у кондитеров такая штука, называется проба на сахар (не путать с анализом при диабете). Делается она так. Шарик расправленного сахара кидают в холодную воду. В зависимости от того, что произойдет, устанавливается цифровая "проба" -  некая степень карамелизации.
Так вот полная карамелизация - это проба (№8, если не путаю), когда шарик отлетает от воды как горох от стенки.

*Если контекст позволяет подобную интерпретацию, то можно не сомневаться, это образ действия, запятых не надо.*
Ну а если подобное явно не по смыслу текста, то соглашусь с Людмилой.

(+)
Людмила дала ссылку на текст, карамельную версию снимаю.

Comment: http://do.gendocs.ru/docs/index-218102.html?page=2
Реже возникали ситуации, когда исправить дело одним приездом было невозможно. На ЧМК заклинился секционный редуктор хода разливочного крана. ... и вместе с его представителем мы поднялись на кран. Крышка была снята и видны расколовшиеся зубья. Форма излома не соответствовала линии действия напряжений и я позволил себе ударить по зубьям. Они отлетали, как сахарные. Было сквозная прокалка до высокой твердости. Изготовители хотели упрочнить своё изделие и выполнили колеса из стали 60С2 по своей инициативе.

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила. Да, здесь кондитерского контекста быть не может. Сдаюсь. Сравнение.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая перед КАК не ставится, если дальнейший оборот имеет значение В КАЧЕСТВЕ: "Его пригласили на совещание как эксперта в данной области". Так что в предложении про бычка на верёвочке запятая может придать смысловой нюанс. Не ставится также при употреблении устойчивых выражений: "Всё шло как по маслу". А при сравнениях ставится всегда.